# Jquery $.post not working as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mongodb

I'm creating a web app using `PHP`, `JQuery`, and `MongoDB` and was running into some trouble with `$.post`. I have a page with a table where each row is marked by a custom button designed in CSS. I use the following script to get the index of that button and pass it to a PHP file. This gets the correct index and posts it to the file just fine.

```
<script>
$(".completed").click(function() {
    var index = $(".completed").index(this);
    $.post("lock.php", {position: index});
});
</script>
```

`lock.php` is supposed to put this index into a session variable and load a new page called `display_page.php`, but `display_page` never gets loaded and no errors are displayed in Firebug. I've tried posting to `display_page` directly but this does not change anything. Here is what my lock.php looks like:

```
<?php
   $pos = $_POST['position'];
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['index'] = $pos;
   header('Location: display_page.php');
?>
```

If anyone could point my in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting in your code.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh That didn't change anything, but now I've noticed my post has a 302 error

Comment: your `header('Location: display_page.php');` in `lock.php` will not redirect your `$.post()` calling page. You need to redirect in javascript on `$.post()` success

Comment: You cannot use a `header()` redirect in an ajax call. You need to redirect in javascript instead.

Comment: I tried using $location.attr('href',url); instead of a header() in lock.php and now lock has a 200 code and display_page never gets called

Comment: You need to make your PHP code send a response that tells your JS code to redirect.  Or, don't use AJAX at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do like below:-

```
<script>
    $(".completed").click(function() {
       var index = $(".completed").index(this);
       $.post("lock.php", {position: index},function( data ){ 
            if(data == 'success'){ // check the response
                window.location.href = 'display_page.php'; // if response is success then redirect to the page
            }else{
              // some alert message
            }
       });
    });
    </script>
```

And in php page:-

```
<?php
   session_start(); // first write this session start code
   if(isset($_POST['position'])){ // check values are coming or not
    $pos = $_POST['position'];
    $_SESSION['index'] = $pos;
    echo "success"; // return success to ajax
   }else{
       echo "failure"; // return failure to ajax
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: This did nothing for me, it doesn't even post now

Comment: `if(data = 'success')` should be `if(data == 'success')`

Comment: yes sorry for that mistake. i edited that. thanks @Sean

Comment: Oh wow I should've caught that. I ended up getting it working with a combination of this and Francis Rodrigues' response below.

Comment: @php-novice . thanks for marking. And i also checked my code. it's working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a many differents callback:

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});
```

The jqXHR Object

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jqxhr-object